# Add feature to see jobs that allow remote from other countries

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I use the UK Careers site and when I search for “allows remote” positions I get a lot of USA jobs in the results. It's hard to know whether they would accept an application from another country (some explicitly say they don't though).

It would be good if the ones that don't allow remote workers from different countries could be filtered out too somehow.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. When placing an ad they should ask what countries you would accept applicants from, which could have an 'any' option.

Comment: Yes, I applied to some offering remote but never heard back. Don't know if it was because I am in another country (India).